# Prompt recently entered values for forms without getting submitted and not ajax posting to any urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am running a simple Embedded web-server where a form needs to be filled and the data can be submitted in 3 different ways for a Truck weighing operation. As i am having 3 different buttons to submit the data through an ajax call to a lua webserver i don't want the form gets submitted in default way.

```
<form id="formTruck" class="form-group">
   <label class="form-label" for="reg-num">Rego:</label>
   <input class="form-input" type="text" id="rego">       
   <label class="form-label" for="product">Product:</label>
   <input class="form-input" type="text" id="product">
   <label class="form-label" for="valuePT">Preset Tare</label>
   <input class="form-input" type="text" id="valuePT">
   <input id="dump-submit" style="display:none" value="Submit_Dump" type="submit"> 
   </form>
<div id="weighInOutGroup">
    <button id="weighIn" onclick="weigh(this.id);">WEIGH IN</button>
    <button id="weighOut" onclick="weigh(this.id);">WEIGH OUT</button>
    <button id="weighInPt" onclick="weigh(this.id);">WEIGH IN (PT)</button>             
</div>
```

I have JS function to do the ajax request depends on the button clicked

```
function weigh(type) {
    var weighData = {};     
    if (type == "weighIn") {            
        $.ajax({
            //ajax request
        },
    });         
    } else if (type == "weighInPt") {           
        //ajax request
    } else if (type == "weighOut") {
        //ajax
    }
};
```

Also i have used following jquery function to prevent pressing enter navigating to default action

```
$("#formTruck").submit(function(e){     
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("weighIn submit prevented")
});
```

but by doing this i couldn't get the recent inputs prompted on text input fields, as the form is not actually submitted in default action.

Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this without doing any posts or navigating to any pages?

Comment: Just use a form serializer to get the data refer https://api.jquery.com/serialize/#serialize

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem, because your script works (_after fixing the syntax errors_): https://jsbin.com/duyapuroku/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you use 3 send buttons, use instead a radio buttons, in the jquery submit add your if's and for catch the form data use $("#formTruck").serialize()

```
$("#formTruck").submit(function(e){     

    console.log("weighIn submit prevented");

    let data = $("#formTruck").serialize() ;

    if ($("#rdWeighIn").prop("checked")) {
        $.ajax({ data: data, ...
    } else if ($("#rdWeighOut").prop("checked")) {
        $.ajax({ data: data, ...
    } else if ($("#rdWeighInPt").prop("checked")) {
        $.ajax({ data: data, ...
    } else {
    // 
    }
return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @imperezivan, I would do that but this is a truck weighing Embedded system application and for the easy operations of the truck drivers the Clients need Three buttons to clearly distinguish the operations. Some how i need Three buttons for the next steps.